# Is there an equivalent of gatherer for Duels of the Planeswalkers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx) is a fantastic resource for finding cards in paper magic, but does not seem to me to contain any way of getting only Duels of the Planeswalkers cards. Neither the Expansion, Format or Block filters contain anything like Duels 2015 (although the expansion filter contains several Duels of planeswalker1 vs planeswalker2). Does some other searchable database exist that contains the Duels 2015 cards only?

---

**Edit/clarification**:
There is a [Duels of the Planeswalkers theme set][2]. To clarify: I am not interested in those cards, but instead the Duels of the Planeswalkers video game and specifically the 2015 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A searchable card list is available for the current version of the game, Magic Duels, at http://www.magicduelscardlist.com

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a searchable database like Gatherer that lists DotP cards, because most places that allow you to search for cards either get their info from Gatherer or MagicCards.info (or a thrid party that gets their info from one of those sources like MtGJSON) and neither of those sites allow you to search for DotP cards. There are however places that list all, or most of the cards from each expansion.

[DotP 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922070037/http://community.wizards.com/forum/mtg-duels-planeswalkers/threads/4104891) + [Expansion](http://www.examiner.com/article/magic-2015-garruk-s-revenge-card-list)
[DotP 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101094058/https://community.wizards.com/forum/mtg-duels-planeswalkers/threads/3924271)
[DotP 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920044649/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/digital/duelsoftheplaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/d13/decklists) + [Expansion](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921090812/http://archive.wizards.com:80/Magic/digital/duelsoftheplaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/d13/expansion)
[DotP 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920050302/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/digital/duelsoftheplaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/d12/decks)
[DotP (2009)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920015744/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/digital/duelsoftheplaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/dotp/decks/and/unlocks)

Comment: There are card lists, but I am looking for something searchable. Also note that the 2015 link that you posted is not up to date: there have been several more booster-packs added such as Masters of Monsters (http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/master-monsters-pack-2015-02-11) and Khans of Tarkir (http://steamcommunity.com/games/255420/announcements/detail/116307939440612706)

Comment: @Jonny Unfortunately that doesn't exist, lists are the best you are going to be able to do. Most 3rd party sites that allow for card searching seem to use either Gatherer or MagicCards.info (or something that gets its info from on of those sites like MtGJSON) So since neither of those sites has them it is very unlikely that you will find a site that does.

Comment: *"It does not exist, but here is the next best thing."* is a valid answer. +1 from me until someone proves otherwise.